# Ruby on Rails: Wrong number of arguments troubleshooting

Tags: exception, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, actioncontroller

Ok, I know this *sounds* like a question already asked, but please trust me and read on.

I am writing a Rails 4 application. I have a Comments class that can apply to multiple other classes (client, project, etc.). The idea is, I pass a parent object as follows:

"<%= link_to "Add comment to #{@audit.name}", new_comment_path(audit_id: @audit.id) %>"

Within my comments controller, I have logic to determine how to assign the comment.

I also allow parameters as follows:

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:narrative, :version, :last_updated_by, :support, :client_id, :control_id, :test_id, :step_id, :audit_id)
end
```

What is defeating me is, I get the 'wrong number of parameters: 1 for 0' error when I click the link defined above, with the error pointing to the comment_params code as the problem. I *thought* that the point of the comment_params method was to work out what to allow (and note: audit_id is on the list of allowable parameters). However, it appears that this method is not accepting parameters. The error has to be simple and syntactic, but I cannot figure it out.

My questions are 1) how would I diagnose this issue and 2) what have I misunderstood with regard to passing parameters, if such is obvious to the more experienced among you? I am flat out of ideas, and Google / SE results generally show problems understanding what the error means, which I don't think is the problem here. I have read and understood the error, but not enough to actually fix it - the problem is with the code that actually defines acceptable parameters!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look for code calling the comment_params method

Comment: Thank you, Frederick. For those reading this, the issue was not initial entry to the controller as I thought it was, but in my calling the comment_params method within the controller from within the 'new' method. Blinding flash of the obvious, I just didn't see it.